# Why does SQL Server HASHBYTES work differently from Oracle STANDARD_HASH?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, hash

Any idea why the two hashing functions in SQL Server and Oracle yield different results when hashing the non-breaking space character?

Oracle `select standard_hash('a ', 'MD5') from dual;` results in `25EF28EB5A5BE667C6222418E9E27E8E` and doesn't match SQL `select HASHBYTES ('MD5','a ');` results in `CE8F03020C81133B3A082F8051EB9FF6`.  Note the space after the input 'a' is a non-breaking space character.

Is there any good source that can lay out the differences?

Comment: From the doc, "The optional method argument lets you specify the name of the hash algorithm to be used. Valid algorithms are SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, and MD5. If you omit this argument, then SHA1 is used"  Does SS use the same?

Comment: *"Note the space after the input 'a' is a non-breaking space character."* rather than stating this, you should include code that actually reproduced this character, such as`'a' + CONVERT(varchar(1),0xA0)`

Comment: Same collation ?

Comment: I pasted in the non-breaking space character, so no need to encode it manually.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, I specified 'MD5' on both sides, but incidentally, the same disagreement happens for SHA2-512 or any hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a character set or "collation" issue, where Oracle is in UTF-8 and SQL Server is in Latin 1252.  My solution was to CONVERT the value to Windows Latin-1252 in Oracle before calculating the hash: `select STANDARD_HASH(CONVERT('a ','WE8MSWIN1252'), 'MD5') from dual`.

To find my collation/character set I did `SELECT collation_name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'MY_DB_NAME';` in SQL Server and `select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';` in Oracle.

Comment: Always the little things

Comment: You could also achieve the Oracle result in SQL Server by encoding the string to UTF-8 when hashing it, e.g.: `select HASHBYTES ('MD5', cast(N'a' + nchar(160) collate LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 as varchar(3)));`

Comment: Alternatively you could just use `nvarchar` on both sides to get UTF-16. Note also that there is server, database and column collation, and these are used for different things

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to establish which one is actually yielding "different" results:

Using your favourite search engine to find online hash generators and testing results.

### External Resources

https://passwordsgenerator.net/md5-hash-generator/  - 99020CB24BD13238D907C65CC2B57C03

https://www.md5hashgenerator.com/  - 99020cb24bd13238d907c65cc2b57c03

https://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php  - 99020cb24bd13238d907c65cc2b57c03

### SQL Server

```
select HASHBYTES ('MD5', 'a ')
```

SQL Server 2014 SP3 (12.0.6024.0)  - 0x99020CB24BD13238D907C65CC2B57C03

SQL Server 2019 (15.0.2080.9)  - 0x99020CB24BD13238D907C65CC2B57C03

### Oracle (using https://dbfiddle.uk/)

```
select standard_hash('a ', 'MD5') from dual;
```

Oracle 21c - 0x99020CB24BD13238D907C65CC2B57C03

Oracle 18c - 0x99020CB24BD13238D907C65CC2B57C03

Oracle 11gR2 - "ORA-00904: "STANDARD_HASH": invalid identifier"

### Conclusion

You can see that your Oracle produced answer differs even from other Oracle answers. What version of Oracle are you running? What other options are set, such as collation etc.?